# How to download an entire dynamic page with wget?

Tags: wget

I'm trying to download a page from a website with the wget command in Linux, what I want to get is the information contained in the html code of the page,  for instance.

I've tried using R's Rvest and Python's beautiful soup for it but it didn't work, so now I'm trying with wget and mostly I get scripts in .css and .js which I can't extract useful information from (as far as I know), so to summarize I would like to extract information of a  from a dynamic site using the wget command.

I've used the arguments -F, -i and some others, bear in mind that I'm fairly new to computer science and Linux in general, so if this question is trivial please explain it nonetheless, thanks.

Also, if necessary I can post what I've done up until now.

Comment: I can't understand what it is that you're looking for? Wget will download the HTML source of the page and with `-p` the related page requisites as well. What more are you looking for? I'd recommend sharing a copy of what you expect and what you actually get.

Comment: Do you mean bottomless pages?

Answer (score 0):

with VBA and https://phantomjs.org/

```
sDir = ThisWorkbook.Path
sCmd = "cmd.exe /K cd """ & sDir & """ & phantomjs.exe phm_save.js " & sURL & " > " & sFile
pid = Shell(sCmd, vbHide)
```

phm_save.js

```
   var system = require('system');
   var page = require('webpage').create();

   page.open(system.args[1], function(){
       console.log(page.content);
       phantom.exit();
    }
   );
```